# How to display events in Calendar (https://fullcalendar.io/) base on monthly, weekly and daily same time

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have an issue with display the calendar event in daily, weekly and monthly according to user requirement.

I used the: https://fullcalendar.io/

This is our database structure: http://prntscr.com/i4rtwi

In Database "repeating_options" fields are there it means :
    0: Daily event
    1: Weekly event
    2: Monthly event

We have only date field it means to start the event from this particular date and display the event the infinite year or you can consider the end date like (31-12-2050).

When we implement using this code :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
        center: '',
        right: 'prev,title,next'
    },
    locale : lang_value,
    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
       view_appointment_info(event.id);
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element, view){
        return (event.ranges.filter(function(range){
            return (event.start.isBefore(range.end) &&
                    event.end.isAfter(range.start));
        }).length)>0;
    },
});
```

When I use the "eventRender" than daily and weekly event working fine but not working monthly. Monthly event displays daily bases instead of display once in the month.

Sample JSON event data:

```
[
  {
    "dow":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "ranges":[{"start":"2018-01-20","end‌​":"2050-12-31"}],
    "id‌​":"1",
    "title":"Repea‌​t Daily",
    "start":"15:54:00",
    "end":"16:24:00",
    "type":"",
    "color"‌​:"#f6cacb"
  },
  {
    "dow":[‌​"3"],
    "ranges":[{"sta‌​rt":"2017-12-20","en‌​d":"2050-12-31"}],
    "i‌​d":"2",
    "title":"Repe‌​at Weekly",
    "start":"17:05:00",
    "end":"17:35:00",
    "type":"","color‌​":"#e73e97"
  },
  {
    "repea‌​t":1,
    "ranges":[{"sta‌​rt":"2018-01-01","en‌​d":"2050-12-31"}],
    "i‌​d":"3",
    "title":"Repe‌​at Monthly",
    "start":"21:16:00",
    "end":"21:46:00",
    "type":"",
    "colo‌​r":""
  }
]
```

So would you please suggest me how we can solve this issue?

Comment: We need to see your event JSON please. The database example is useful but doesn't tell us how you're creating the JSON for fullCalendar. Since it's this which is used to determine what goes onto the calendar, that's the important part. Show some sample JSON, explain how you expected it to appear, and how it actually appears with your code now.

Comment: [{"dow":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],"ranges":[{"start":"2018-01-20","end":"2050-12-31"}],"id":"1","title":"Repeat Daily","start":"15:54:00","end":"16:24:00","type":"","color":"#f6cacb"},{"dow":["3"],"ranges":[{"start":"2017-12-20","end":"2050-12-31"}],"id":"2","title":"Repeat Weekly","start":"17:05:00","end":"17:35:00","type":"","color":"#e73e97"},{"repeat":1,"ranges":[{"start":"2018-01-01","end":"2050-12-31"}],"id":"3","title":"Repeat Monthly","start":"21:16:00","end":"21:46:00","type":"","color":""}]

I am not sure it is enough for you.

Comment: There's nothing in your code which has any relationship to monthly repetition. The eventRender code simply causes the event to be rendered if the start date (of the specific given copy of the event supplied to the render method) falls within the range dates for the event. The repeating on certain days is done by the `dow` property, which, as documented by fullCalendar's website, only supports specific days of a week. It has no support for monthly or other types of repetition. Your code simply has no functionality for what you're suggesting, so it's not really a surprise that it's "not working"

Comment: It's not clear from the wording of your question whether you actually expected it to work or not, and/or whether you've tried to do anything else to solve the problem yourself yet?

Comment: Would you please let us know, which format we need to implement for the repetition so we can display based on day, week and month.

If you have any sample format or code for that then please provide us.

Comment: There isn't enough information within the JSON to know on what day it should be repeated each month, so it's hard to suggest anything. First you need to change your data. Ideally you probably want to specify a specific day of the month (e.g. one from 1st, 2nd...up to 31st (obviously not all months to go to 31, so if you say that it'll skip some months)).

Comment: Yes, It was difficult to explain you.
Let take one thing, If we need to display events on the calendar.
Events may daily, monthly or weekly.

So how you will manage it? There is any sample or example? so we will do it based on your suggestion.

Comment: Did you read my last comment? First you must decide how you want to represent the monthly repetition. Daily and weekly is already taken care of, it works. Monthly is the problem. At the moment I cannot make any suggestion to you because I don't have the right data from you to do a monthly repetition. I can't code against data that doesn't exist. I suggested a way to represent it (day of the month), now you need to confirm if you will do that, or something else, and update your sample JSON to show me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Please check my json array that contain the all data.
Based on this data we need to display the daily,weekly and montly format.
You can change the json format not the fixed but we need to display data according to daily,weekly and monthly.
It would be great if you have any sample format for that.

Comment: You aren't understanding me. **You** need to tell **me** what JSON you can produce to represent the monthly repetition. Then I will build some code from it. I gave you a **suggestion** for a data structure. **You** need to confirm that it's possible for your application to produce that data. I don't have access to your application to know what the possibilities are. I don't want to write code for something which could be impossible for your system to output.

Comment: So I need some JSON which contains a) something to indicate that repetition should be monthly (and not any other frequency), b) the day(s) of the month on which to repeat the event, c) the start/end for the period of repetition. Part c) is already done (via the "ranges" property), but parts a) and b) are missing. Exactly how you represent that is up to you, but as long as it's clear and unambiguous, then you can choose whatever representation is possible from your system. Then show me an example and explain it, and after that I can think of some code to make it show in fullCalendar. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience,

We need to display this event on a monthly basis (http://prntscr.com/i7069o) but right now it is displaying daily bases. 

this is (http://prntscr.com/i7069o) my JSON array which contains the monthly event. In the screenshot above 2 arrays ( without red marked ) is working fine with "daily" and "weekly" but see the red marked area it is "monthly" event and it's not working fine.
Would you please let me know which part is missing or incorrect for monthly (red mark) event. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I already understand all that, that's exactly what you said in the main question. You haven't answered my question at all. I have written my request more than once in different ways. Do you actually understand what I'm asking you to provide?

Comment: You say "my JSON array which contains the monthly event."...but actually look at it: `{
    "repea‌​t":1,
    "ranges":[{"sta‌​rt":"2018-01-01","en‌​d":"2050-12-31"}],
    "i‌​d":"3",
    "title":"Repe‌​at Monthly",
    "start":"21:16:00",
    "end":"21:46:00",
    "type":"",
    "colo‌​r":""
  }` . Tell me in there, which pieces of information indicate 1) that repetition must be monthly, and b) which day of the month to show the event? The answer is that information is missing. Until you provide it and show how it looks I can't write any code which would use it to adjust the calendar

Comment: And I'm asking _you_ to provide the data because it's _your_ PHP which has to generate it, and I can't see your PHP and don't know what information is possible for it to display.

Comment: Sorry! again.

Let's consider scenario for it,

We need to display monthly event from 2018-01-01 to 2050-12-31. 

and need to display in every "5th date" of month

like "2018-01-05", "2018-02-05" and so on till "2050-12-05".

I hope now you got your answer.

Thanks

Comment: Ok so can I assume that your JSON will become `{ "frequency":"m", "ranges":[{"sta‌​rt":"2018-01-01","en‌​d":"2050-12-31"}], "dom": [5], "i‌​d":"3", "title":"Repe‌​at Monthly", "start":"21:16:00", "end":"21:46:00", "type":"", "colo‌​r":"" }` where `"frequency": "m"` means "repeat at this frequency: monthly" and `"dom": [5]` means "day(s) of the month to repeat on: 5th" (it's an array so could have more days in it if required). Can your system produce JSON like that from your stored data and provide it to fullCalendar?

Comment: According to your suggestion we implement solution and make json array like this :
[{"dow":[5],"frequency":"m","ranges":[{"start":"2018-01-05","end":"2050-12-31"}],"id":"3","title":"Repeat Monthly","start":"21:16:00","end":"21:46:00","type":"","color":""}]
and will provide to calendar but it's showing like this : http://prntscr.com/i72pl9

Actually, it needs to display once on a 5th date.

Please check and let me know what is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: read more carefully. `dom` not `dow`. I'm suggesting a custom field which we can use to make new functionality. if you can provide that, then I'll write some more custom code to make use of it. As I already explained in the very early comments, `dow` doesn't do what you need, and neither does the existing code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164075/discussion-between-kamlesh-and-adyson).

Comment: Dom is not working for me 

When I use "dom" it will display them on daily basis see in this screenshot: prntscr.com/i72u4f 

My new json array is : 
[{"dom":[5],"frequency":"m","ranges":[{"start":"2018-01-05","end":"2050-12-31"}],"id":"3","title":"Repeat Monthly","start":"21:16:00","end":"21:46:00","type":"","color":""}]

Comment: Have you been reading **anything** I've written? Of course it doesn't work. That's the whole point. This is just part 1 - sort out the data format. Part 2 is write the code to make use of it. That's what I can do now we have an agreed data format. I will take some time to think about it. Please try and pay attention. I feel like I have been talking to the wind. If you don't understand what I'm writing then please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now we have an agreed format (as per the comments) for providing sufficient information for monthly repeating events, we can write some code to make the calendar display monthly events.

For the benefit of future readers I'll explain the agreed format here. For a monthly event, we will add two extra custom properties, in addition to the already custom `ranges` property (which is already used to determine the start and end of the period(s) of repetition):

1) `"frequency": "m"` - this signifies that the event should repeat monthly.

2) `"dom": [1, 3, 5]` - this array will contain the day(s) of the month on which to repeat the event. In this example, the event will repeat on the 1st, 3rd and 5th day of the month, providing those days fall within the dates defined in `ranges`

So an event which repeats monthly will look like this:

```
{
  "dom": [5], //new property
  "frequency": "m", //new property
  "ranges": [{
    "start": "2018-01-05",
    "end": "2050-12-31"
  }],
  "id": "3",
  "title": "Repeat Monthly",
  "start": "21:16:00",
  "end": "21:46:00",
  "type": "",
  "color": ""
}
```

This event is designed to repeat monthly on the 5th of each month between 21:16 and 21:46. This pattern will start on 5th Jan 2018 and end on 31st December 2050.

We then need to amend the code in the existing "eventRender" callback to take account of this extra information and use it to decide whether to place the event onto the calendar on any given day:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
  //check if this instance of the event (one per day is generated for events with only time in their start/end properties) is within any of the ranges defined for it:
  if ((event.ranges.filter(function(range) {
      return (event.start.isBefore(range.end) &&
        event.end.isAfter(range.start));
    }).length) > 0) {
    if (event.frequency == "m") { //check whether repetition is monthly
      return ($.inArray(event.start.date(), event.dom) > -1); //show the event if the date of the month is in the defined days of the month for this event
    } else {

      return true;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  };
},
```

N.B. The original code dealt with daily and weekly repetition already via the `ranges` and the `dow` properties, it was only data and functionality for monthly repetition which was missing.

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/173/ for a working demonstration.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! you have saved my lot of time. :)

We have more options with calendar, but if we have any issues with this option then we will update you on the same question.

Comment: No problem. Once we sorted out the format, the actual new bit of code, as you can see, is pretty simple. I think it should work well. If you get stuck with any other implementations using fullCalendar, then please add more questions, I usually look at the fullcalendar questions regularly.

Comment: Ok Thank You  ADyson

Comment: Is it possible to remove particular event from calendar ?
Suppose my event is daily from 2018-01-20 to 2050-12-31.
I need to remove two particular date event like 2018-01-25 & 2018-02-05 from daily event.
It's not fixed, sometime 3 or not 5 event need to remove also.

Would you please let me know the solution for that is possible in full calendar?

Comment: It would be great if you provide an example for the same because we need to pass date instead of id.

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you? "idOrFilter may also be a filter function that accepts one Event Object argument and returns true if it should be removed." If you have access to the event object you can of course check the date in order to make your decision

Comment: Yes, But which dateformat  we need to pass in removeEvents and date may be more than one.

My script look like this  :

Comment: Then within the function you need to check the event's date against all your possible dates in turn until you find a matching one. It's a simple loop. Sorry I don't have time to do this right now, but I'm sure you are not so helpless that you cannot write a loop. You can use momentJS's comparison functions to compare the dates - go and look up the documentation and give it a try.